# Visual Studio 2012 C++ Empty Project error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I keep attempting to make a new C++ Empty Project Console App but when I make the project the VS (2012) screen literally is empty. No place to write my code, how do I fix?

[image]

Comment: Hello there, can you spare a moment to talk about our saviour GNU Make?

Comment: I'd love to but I'm still a beginner, let me just learn with the IDE first.

Comment: The meaning of the word "empty" in Empty Project is not ambiguous.  You'll have to stop being a beginner, and then some, before you're ready to completely configure a project from scratch.  It can wait.

Comment: @HansPassant That's what I said...

Answer (score 0):

That is what a empty project is. If you want a file (place to write code) you have to right click on a folder and add a source file. I suggest calling it main.cpp. You must also have a main function inside of it.

```
int main()
{
    return 1;
}
```

As a beginner I dont suggest you start empty projects.

You probably want to create a console application. That will give you a place to write your code.

Comment: I was beginning projects with the same settings yesterday and the day prior. I was able to write in the project every time I did so, any ideas why that was occurring? I'm sure I'll figure it out as I progress, just wondering.

Comment: Are you sure it was the exact same settings? Maybe "Empty project" was ticked?

Comment: It was ticked, ticking "Empty project" are the instructions. I'm attempting to create a simple Hello,World project but I have no directory. It's all empty.

Comment: the following is a re-post of a comment I left to another responder in this thread: "I selected "I created a Win32 Console Application for Visual C++, this prompts up the "Application Settings" page. In that page I select "Empty project", as I want to write a console app project from scratch. But, nothing is there. Nothing. It's an empty directory, no file. Nothing."

Comment: That is exactly what it is supposed to do. You do not want a empty project. You want a console project. Which is a empty project with a source file in it. If some instructions told you to make a empty project the next step should be telling you to create a file in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create an empty project.
Create "Win32 Console Application". It will create main file method into which you can insert your code

Comment: http://imgur.com/T9iB6ZX
These are the options I've been using, last times I began project with these settings I was able to type. Now it's fully empty. I realize now that that is what an emptyproject is, but why was I able to code prior to today?

Comment: Under Additional options, uncheck "Empty project". This will create an application entry point into which you can insert code. When you choose an empty project you'd not got "Application Settings" page.